# API is getting hit twice while returning audio file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i am returning an audio file from web api. requirement is to play the media file instead of downloading,i am using this code.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("audiofile/download", Name = "GetAudioFile")]

    public HttpResponseMessage GetAudioFile(string q)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q))
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };
        }
        String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AudioUploads/");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(path, q);
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath))
        };
        var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(filePath));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
        return response;
    }
```

i noticed that this action method is being hit twice as like [image]

Can anyone suggest why its happening? why my api method is being called twice?

P.S I am using Url.Link in order to make uploaded file url. when i hit that, api method is called twice.

Answer (score 1):

Servers only respond to requests. They can't initiate a communication with a client, without initial request.
That said, your client code is to blame here, as it's sending two requests instead of one, and the server correctly responds to both.

Comment: i am hitting my api from browser...so you are saying it browser that is doing it wrong?

Comment: Is there a player which automatically loads in the browser?

Comment: default browser player, embedded in chrome. i just hit the url and it comes over to play the audio.

Comment: I believe the first request is from browser, and the second request is already from the player to download and play the audio.

Comment: The browser first determines the response and loads the handler for the registered response type, which is the media player. Then the player opens and calls the endpoint again to stream the data. As you can see from the download-size, the browser requests are tiny, which indicates they didn't actually download full content, but just the info required to understand how to handle it and then initiated the player passing in the media URL.

Comment: good point, what if i give this API to mobile developer in order to play audio on device, do you think he will also has to make two request?

Comment: It depends how the developer is going to consume it. If the context it's being consumed already knows that the content is an audio file, there won't be a need to do that twice. Rather he'll just load the handle and pass in the URL to it directly, without initially querying it.